# SQL Server Stored Procedure Optimization

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

I have the following stored procedure running against an `ExtractedMessages` table which might contain up to 100M records (100,000,000).

For the purpose of my application, this stored procedure should run in less than one second

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetNextMessages 
    @taskId bigint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ci INT
    DECLARE @cr INT

    SELECT 
        @ci = CurrentIndex, @cr = CurrentResources 
    FROM
        ExtractedTasks 
    WHERE
        Id = @taskId

    UPDATE ExtractedTasks 
    SET CurrentIndex = @ci + @cr 
    WHERE Id = @taskId

    SELECT * 
    FROM ExtractedMessages 
    WHERE TaskId = @taskId
    ORDER BY Id 
        OFFSET @ci ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @cr ROWS ONLY
END
```

NB: cr can not be more than 1500

Comment: note that _ExtractedMessages_ table is already indexed on _Id_ and on _TaskId_

Comment: You have weird pagination logic.

Comment: Do you really need all the columns in result ? If no, then remove the `*` and add only required columns

Comment: Yes I do need all the columns, maybe I can spare one or two
Plus, It only has 10 columns

Comment: What do the execution plans show?

Comment: You should provide execution plan in XML format. See https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: And how much time this SP currently taking?

Comment: I'm currently waiting for the next automatic execution to paste the execution plan.@BogdanSahlean @Richard

Comment: The SP took 2 secs when I had 4 million records,
I haven't yet reached the maximum theoretical bound of 100M @Viking

Comment: Remove the first select - it's redundant. You can update the table directly with `set CurrentIndex = CurrentIndex + CurrentResources`. Then just buy enough RAM to fit your entire database into

Comment: @JalalShahoud, make sure you have a composite clustered index on `TaskId` and `Id` along with a unique non-clustered index on `Id` (maybe with `CurrentIndex` and `CurrentResources` as included columns). That should provide decent performance but be aware that row number based pagination time will still slow proportionally by the specified `OFFSET`.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - You can't remove it. The variables are used in final `select` for pagination

Comment: Oh you're right it is used. It is indeed a very strange pagination requirement when the pagination settings are on the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everyone for your kind help
I was able to identify the problem, after all it was a memory management issue on the server that is running SQL server. I have increased the dedicated memory of the server. And the issue has been resolved. The SP works smoothly now

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying your table twice you could do the following:

```
DECLARE @ci INT
DECLARE @cr INT

DECLARE @T TABLE (
    ci INT
    , cr INT
    );

UPDATE ExtractedTasks
SET CurrentIndex = CurrentIndex + CurrentResources
OUTPUT DELETED.CurrentIndex, DELETED.CurrentResources
INTO @T (ci, cr)
WHERE Id = @taskId;

SELECT 
    @ci = ci, @cr = cr
FROM
    @T

SELECT * 
FROM ExtractedMessages
WHERE TaskId = @taskId
ORDER BY Id 
    OFFSET @ci ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @cr  ROWS ONLY
```

The key here is OUTPUT clause. It's going to insert deleted records (pre-update values) into a table variable. Which means you replace multiple selects from a table with one. Other than correct indexes I don't see anything for improvement.

Also, make sure you select just the columns you need, not everything. It's generally a good practice to list exact columns you need.

Comment: +1 But now that I could reproduce the problem,
a simple count(*) on the table is taking 6 secs

Comment: Attach execution plans, otherwise there's not much we can help.